# Java Print number square with revolving numbers using nested for loops

Tags: java

/*Here's the full question:
Write a method called printSquare that takes in two integer parameters, a min and a max, and prints the numbers in the range from min to max inclusive in a square pattern. The square pattern is easier to understand by example than by explanation, so take a look at the sample method calls and their resulting console output in the table below.

Each line of the square consists of a circular sequence of increasing integers between min and max. Each line prints a different permutation of this sequence. The first line begins with min, the second line begins with min + 1, and so on. When the sequence in any line reaches max, it wraps around back to min.

You may assume the caller of the method will pass a min and a max parameter such that min is less than or equal to max. */

Hi guys I've got this problem I can't solve. It's to call this method `printSquare(1,5)`;
to get this output:

```
12345

23451

34512

45123

51234
```

so far here's my code. I cant seem to get the front numbers to shift to the back.

```
public static void printSquare (int startNum, int height){

        if (startNum == height){
            System.out.print(height);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = startNum; i <= height; i++){
            int max = startNum;
            int j = i;
            for (j = i; j <= height; j++){
                System.out.print (j); 
            }

        System.out.println();
        }            
}
```

Comment: You want to shift to the left until the 5 is the front and print it for every shift? The difference between every number will always be 1?

Answer (score 3):

If your inner loop starts with `i`, it has to end with `height + i`, not just `height` for the output to be square, otherwise it will be a triangle. You want to learn about the *modulo* operator `%` to determine the *remainder* of a division in order to handle the "overflow".

The specification you gave is unclear about what should happen regarding the "overflow" if `startNum != 1`.

Besides, the guard condition `(startNum == height)` is clearly wrong if `height` actually means *height* (and, because it says *printSquare*, the *width*). I would expect `printSquare(4, 4)` to print four rows and columns, not just one row and one column. Something  seems to be wrong with the naming.
*In general such guards are suspicious. The code of algorithms should be so generic that it doesn't need to handle such special cases separately.*

Here's a possible implementation which works for the cases `printSquare(1, 5);` and     `printSquare(1, 1);`. For other cases, your specification wasn't clear enough.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        printSquare(1, 5);
        printSquare(1, 1);
        //printSquare(2, 6);
        //printSquare(4, 4);
    }

    public static void printSquare(int startNum, int height) {
        for (int i = startNum; i < startNum + height; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < height + i; j++) {
                System.out.print((j - 1) % height + 1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If the end number is not determined by `height` alone but by `startNum + height - 1`, a possible solution looks like this:

```
    public static void printSquare(int startNum, int height) {
        for (int i = startNum; i < startNum + height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                System.out.print((j + i - startNum) % (height) + startNum);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: It does not work for ranges of `5-8` for example. Apart from that it looks good.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? `printSquare(5, 8)` works fine. If you think it doesn't, that's fine, but given the specification *both* of our interpretations are within the spec. As I said, the specification wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I assume that it should print `5678`, `6785`, `7856`, `8567`. And no, it is not a hundred percent clear on that. One can only do assumptions.

Comment: Given that the specification calls the second parameter `height`, not `endNum`, I claim that one of the following is wrong: this assumption, or the specification. P.S.: Not trying to pick on your assumption. I find your assumption totally valid, I'm picking on the unclear specification.

Comment: Hey thanks! but it only works for the question posted but not for this example. 
printSquare(3, 9);

3456789

4567893

5678934

6789345

7893456

8934567

9345678

Comment: Did you already try taking the code and changing it according to the refined requirements specification yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Providing an alternative java 8 solution using lambdas. It could be an overkill for a simple task

```
public static void printSquaresJava8(int x, int y) {
  int count = y - x + 1;
  IntStream sequence = (IntStream.rangeClosed(x, y).<Integer>flatMap(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(i, i + y).limit(count).<Integer>map(j -> j > y ? j - count : j)));
  List<Integer> numbers = sequence.boxed().collect(Collectors.<Integer>toList());

  IntStream.<Integer>rangeClosed(0,count-1).forEach(i ->
                                           {numbers.subList(count * i, count + count*i).forEach(j -> System.out.print(j + " "));
                                             System.out.println();
                                           }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Written in c++. Call numberSquare(1, 5) Your first for-loop is your row, the second nested for-loop is your column(s). k starts at min value. the col for loop will print out k from min to max, in the first iteration it will print out 1 2 3 4 5 horizontally. once k is equal to max, reset it to min so that the outer loop. can print out the rows from 1 to 5. think if it like a 2D array or a grid.

```
 void numberSquare(int min, int max) {
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        int k = i;
        for(int j = min; j <= max; j++) {
            cout << k;
            if (k == max) {
                k = min;
            } 
            else k = k+1;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```